# Using Material theme in Chrome Extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, angular-material

I am noob for browser extension development and want to use 'purple-green' Material theme for Chrome browser extension.

I tried below suggestion but both didn't work:

- Link stylesheet directly into html like `<link  rel="stylesheet"
  href="./purple-green.css">` And
- Add it in manifest.json like `"content_scripts": [{"css":
  ["purple-green.css"]}]`

When i am adding some styles manually in the file, they are being reflected and i can see the css file fetched in browser's "Network" tab also. But, matetial's form control styles are not reflecting in the plugin.

Sample code link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-curie-r71bx

Comment: The content scripts run in web pages, not in your extension. Assuming you have popup.html declared in `browser_action` you should simply use the standard `<link>` tag in that html file. If you need more help please add [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question.

Comment: Thank you for the content script explanation. I added the sample code at https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-curie-r71bx. And your assumption is correct that i want to add these styles to popped up window.

Comment: `<link>` tag is the right choice then. Make sure you're using the correct classes. For example, there's no such thing as `matInput` attribute, but there is a `mat-input-element` class.

Comment: Tried with classes already like `<input class="mat-input-element">` and `<h1 class="mat-title" color="primary">Quick Pay</h1>`. But still not working.

Comment: I think it's a debugging problem at this point. Right-click the popup, click "inspect" and see what's actually happening.